# (Help) Package standard DLLs in the executable

Tags: dll, package, mingw, mingw-w64

When I compile anything with G++ (MinGW64), the executable needs these DLLs: 'libgcc_s_seh-1.dll', 'libstdc++-6.dll' and 'libwinpthread-1.dll'. I would like these DLLs "inside" the executable. Can I do this? Thanks

Comment: Thanks! This help me, but to write this command is soooooooooooooooooooooooo bored XD

Comment: Writting g++ -Wall -o main.exe main.cpp -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -L lpthread

Comment: No, thanks! Im happy (but bored!!)

Comment: The first is good, the second not ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to this question. You only have to add this to your command at the end:

-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -L lpthread